# Is functor meant for faster running time (C++11)?

Tags: c++, callback, functor, c++17

I know what the functor and callback function are.
But does a  functor effect on the performance side?

Should all the functions be implemented as functors?

I don't know when to use functor.

Comment: If you want to talk about performance you either need to check if both cases generate the same assembler code or write benchmarks. The first will probably be good enough here.

Comment: Use functors when you need to have some state and `static`s aren't good enough.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat thank you, do you have some real-world examples?

Comment: Functors might be more performant. Or they may not be. It depends. And you should not really care about things such as performance when making a program. Not until the very end, and only if it's a requirement. Good enough really is good enough. Concentrate on making good designs that lead to good and well-written code that is easy to read, understand and most importantly of all, is easy to *maintain*.

Comment: This can be reworded as *"When do I use lambdas with state?"*. Examples? How about this: You want to sort a structure by a field selected at runtime (let's assume all fields have a same type). Then you can use `std::sort` with a lambda (or functor) capturing pointer-to-member.

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully this is objective enough and not based on opinion.

> Should all the functions be implemented as functors?

Should? No. Can? Yes.

Use of functors is the best/cleanest when a function template expects a callable object with one set of arguments but the implementation of the callable object needs additional data.

If the callable object does not need additional data, it is better to write a function. Adding the extra fluff to create a functor for such cases is developer overhead that has no benefits.

I would be surprised if performance changes based on whether you use a functor or a function.